# jquery iframe item selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to add class to an iframe (on same domain) element but check some of the same issues here and came up with the solution.

The iframe is next to body tag and the js was place before the body end tag.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-iframe').contents().find('#mnucompany').addClass('is-active');       
    console.log('ok');
});
</script>
```

There is no error showing in console except the OK log but the class was not adding to #mnucompany.

What else could be wrong? Any big hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the Iframe and the site on the same domain ?

Comment: Yes its on same domain. The iframe contains the page heading section with logos and menus.

Comment: Dump here the result of  `$('#my-iframe').length` and `$('#my-iframe').contents().find('#mnucompany').length`

Comment: $('#my-iframe').length return 1     $('#my-iframe').contents().find('#mnucompany').length return 0

Answer (score 1):

After our comments :

You should wait the iframe to be loaded !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#my-iframe').on('load',function (){
    $('#my-iframe').contents().find('#mnucompany').addClass('is-active');       
    console.log('ok');
});
});
```

Comment: Quite strange because the element id in question exist.      <div class="dvmain-navi">
  <ul class="ulmain-navi">
   <li><a id="mnucompany" href="company.html" target="_parent">company</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

Comment: @Jonathan.B What is the result of this  code :`alert( $('#my-iframe').contents().find("[id=mnucompany]")`

Comment: says  [object Object], could be null.

Comment: `alert( $('#my-iframe').contents().find("[id=mnucompany]").length`

Comment: @Jonathan.B No. on the same satage you're at ( when you print screen , put your cursor on the html which is inside the iframe, and press `f2` then copy all  the content (ctrl+A) and paste it in Tinypick again.

Comment: Thanks. Captured it as full separate screenshot. [http://i59.tinypic.com/mhbu3q.jpg] and [http://i61.tinypic.com/t56hhd.jpg]

Comment: @Jonathan.B did it help you ?

Comment: Oh did not notice the update. Now its showing Uncaught Typeerror: $(...).on is not a function. `$('#my-iframe').on('load',function (){...

Comment: @Jonathan.B which jQuery versaion you use ?

Comment: Previously using v1.4.4 with the above error. After updating to v2.0 it shows new error      [code]Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match[/code]

Comment: @Jonathan.B why null ? what is the url for source page and the target iframe ? it can't be access problems since weve shown that you can access the content.

Comment: The issues related to  filesystem origin and chrome was more strict on rules while Firefox and IE work fine. Appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var myVar = setTimeout(function () {
            var $mnuCompany = $('#my-iframe').contents().find('#mnucompany');
            if($mnuCompany.length>0){
                $('#my-iframe').contents().find('#mnucompany').addClass('is-active');       
                console.log('ok');
                clearTimeout(myVar);
            }
        });
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: Though there was no error the code has also no effect. Thanks.